# mysql select if sum greater and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have two mysql tables.
First table:

```
cost_id| cost_customer_id | cost_total | cost_date
 1     |      1           |     50     | 2019-01-03
 2     |      2           |    120     | 2019-02-03
 3     |      1           |     70     | 2019-03-21
 4     |      2           |     35     | 2019-04-03
 5     |      3           |     14     | 2019-05-07
 6     |      1           |     84     | 2019-06-03
```

Second table:

```html
inv_id | inv_customer_id  | inv_total  | inv_date
 1     |      1           |    150     | 2019-01-05
 2     |      2           |     20     | 2019-02-06
 3     |      1           |     90     | 2019-03-21
 4     |      1           |      3     | 2019-04-03
 5     |      3           |     94     | 2019-05-09
 6     |      2           |     11     | 2019-06-08
 7     |      1           |     99     | 2019-07-06
 8     |      2           |     71     | 2019-08-04
 9     |      1           |     45     | 2019-09-02
```

So what I would want returned is:

```html
customer_id | sum_inv_total | sum_cost_total  | balance     | avg_inv_date
     1      |      387      |     204         |   183       | 2019-05-31
     2      |      102      |     155         |   -53       | null
     3      |       94      |      14         |    80       | 2019-05-09
```

ie, to get average inv_date for each customer after deducting costs ordered by inv_date, for example for customer #1; average inv_date of open invoices:

```html
    inv_id | inv_customer_id  | inv_total  | inv_date    | status
     1     |      1           |    150     | 2019-01-05  | closed (still below cost)
     3     |      1           |     90     | 2019-03-21  | open (reached total cost: 204)
     4     |      1           |      3     | 2019-04-03  | open
     7     |      1           |     99     | 2019-07-06  | open
     9     |      1           |     45     | 2019-09-02  | open
```

I can try following query but it takes too long time to finish and for only one customer:

```html
SELECT 
    sum_cost_total,
    SUM(inv_total_str) AS sum_inv_total ,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(inv_date_str))) AS avg_inv_date
FROM
(
    SELECT
        o1.inv_total AS inv_total_str, o1.inv_date AS inv_date_str,
        (
            SELECT SUM(cost_total)
            FROM company_costs 
            WHERE cost_customer_id = o1.inv_company_customer_id
        ) AS sum_cost_total 
    FROM invoices o1
    INNER JOIN 
        invoices o2 ON o2.inv_id <= o1.inv_id AND o1.inv_company_customer_id =  o2.inv_company_customer_id
    WHERE 
        o1.inv_company_customer_id = 1 AND 
        o1.inv_total > 0 
    GROUP BY
        o1.inv_id,
        o1.inv_total
    HAVING
        SUM(o2.inv_total) > sum_cost_total
) t
```

Comment: "average inv_date for each customer after deducting costs ordered by inv_date"  . . . I just have no idea what this means.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Ok, edited now.

Answer (score 0):

Just group cost & invoice separately to have 02 subqueries, then join results to get final result

```
select cost_customer_id as customer_id, sum_cost_total, sum_inv_total, sum_inv_total- sum_cost_total as balance, avg_inv_date from (
select cost_customer_id, sum(cost_total) as sum_cost_total from
company_costs
group by cost_customer_id
) as c_total
inner join (
select inv_customer_id, sum(inv_total) as sum_inv_total, DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(inv_date))), '%Y-%m-%d') AS avg_inv_date from
invoices 
group by inv_customer_id
) as i_total
on c_total.cost_customer_id = i_total.inv_customer_id
```

You should have this result:

[image]

Improve the condition with `sum_inv_total > sum_cost_total` in case of need.